# Is it possible this hub can fit to my 8 speed and 32 spokes?

Tags: mountain-bike

my bro's bike had 7 speed and 36 spokes...
is it possible his hub can fit to my 8 speed and 32 spokes?

Comment: Not very well..

Comment: Are you trying to fit the 32-spoke hub with 36-spoke rim or building with a new rim?

Comment: @RossMillikan Use [edit] to improve it then.

Comment: Do you mean mount his hub onto your rim, or use his complete wheel on your bike?

Comment: what i mean is to transfer his hub to mine, 
his hub attached with 7 speed cog 36 spokes
mine is 8 speed cog 32 spokes... just wondering if his hub can fit to my 8 speed cog? because it seems its possible to attached my spokes to 36 hub holes, but lack 4 of holes because my spokes are 32 which is its ok for me

Answer (score 1):

sprocket spacing between 7 and 8 speed is almost identical therefore 8sp is one sprocket wider than 7sp. For this reason, you can't use a 7speed hub for 8speed sprockets unless you miss one off. you would then also need to ensure the gears are set up safely, so the chain can't be shifted into the spokes.

Comment: it means theres no way the hub will fit to mine?

Comment: @VernonRD you could offer it up and see what it looks like. But you'll probably never get 8 sprockets on that hub

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need: Same hub width, same wheel diameter, rim width which fits your brakes (if you have rim brakes), tire width narrow enough to fit your brakes and frame. The number of spokes doesn’t matter for compatibility.

You’ll probably have to adjust the rear derailleur and you’ll only be able to use 7 of the 8 sprockets. It’s possible because 7 and 8 speed have the same sprocket spacing. I’ve used an 8 speed shifter for a 7 speed cassette, so I see no reason why it shouldn’t be possible the other way around.